# Moving Gitlab and Gitolite server to another machine

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitolite, gitlab

Now, I have gitlab and gitolite running on my ubuntu server. However, this server is too slow and my company wish to move the server to another machine. Are there any way to move gitlab and gitolite server( the whole files, users and setting) to another machine?

Installing and creating all users and repositories again would be my last choice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I am constantly doing this by hourly crontab job for faster local deployment.
 (which creates an exact copy of the original server, serves as a read-only mirror, personally I call it a puppet machine).

All you need to do is:

1. backup/restore mysql data (tools: mysqldump / mysql < backup.sql.txt)
2. copy all gitlab www  to new machine (scp, rsync)
3. copy all gitolite dir to new machine (rsync)

You can always run the following command to test if the puppet is running successful.

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
```

---

**Some detailed procedure:**

I have mime setup done by using ubuntu 12.04 gitolite apt-get install, rest by official guide and I have also made myself some notes:

- reminder at: https://github.com/c2h2/gitlabhq_install/blob/master/aio.sh
- automated backup script: https://github.com/c2h2/gitlabhq_install/blob/master/gitlab_backup.rb

SSH private/public keys are needed for automated (passwordless) rsync/scp process, if you don't understand plz read http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html

All you need to setup is some cron jobs after original machine is working: this is **online** mirror too. (you don't need to restart any webserver/machine)

*crontab on mirror machine:*

```
58 * * * * rsync -zav root@my_remote_server.com:/home/git /home
11 * * * * rsync -zav root@my_remote_server.com:/root/mysql_hourly_dump.txt /root
15 * * * * mysql -u root -p"secure password" gitlabhq_production < mysql_hourly_dump.txt
20 * * * * rsync -zav --delete my_remote_server.com:/www/ /www
```

*crontab on server:*

```
7 * * * * mysqldump -p"secure password" gitlabhq_production -u root > /root/mysql_hourly_dump.txt
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it somehow? I am new to gitlab and gitolite server. Database I am using is sqlite, how can I move that database to another machine? Right now I am access gitlab via Hostname:3000 which is for local uses only so I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: ok i put up some extra info. plz vote up and mark correct answer if you feel helpful.

Comment: if you use SQLite, this should be even easier. skip the mysql part and rsync the SQLite db file.

Comment: I am waiting for Sam to test your answer, but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: I am so sorry for saying this but It would take me 2-3 days. I don't get used to this kind of work and I have no experience. I am just an internee. Therefore, I have to discuss this with my boss before I can really do this. But I will update you as soon as I can. Thank you guys. :)

Answer (score 1):

Moving gitolite seems easy:

- you need to make sure the public keys it references are still in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the new home (so you mainly need to copy that file over)
- And you need to move the `repositories`, `.gitolite` and `.gitolite.rc` files (check the paths in that last one)

The "users" are only declared in the gitolite file and the gitlab database.

GitLab should be reinstalled (because of all the gems it is using, which could be using on fixed path based on the first installation) and its database updated/replaced with the one from the Ubuntu server (either through a file copy, or through an sql export/import).

Comment: I tried to copy and place repositories and gitlab database. But when I want to start the server it's not working. Git repositories aren't imported to gitlab anyway. I don't know where I have to change the config files. Thank you anyway.